# How to override style of sorted dataTable?

Tags: css, angularjs, datatables

i'm basically trying to figure out how to change the style of this particular element in dataTable

[image]

Here the HTML:

```
<table id="oldFornitures" class="table" datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions" >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-order">{{'POD' | translate}}</th>
```

and here dtOptions:

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
            .withOption('bFilter', false)
            .withOption('responsive', true)
            .withOption('sScrollY','40vh')
            .withOption('sScrollCollapse', true)
            .withOption('sScrollX', 'auto')
            .withLanguage({ "sEmptyTable": "Nessuna fornitura presente","sInfoEmpty" : ""})
            .withOption('bPaginate', false);
```

That's the image that let us see the order of the column in the header, and i want to replace it with another style

how it is possible?

Comment: Is that a background image?? could you please share the code

Comment: @mahip_j pasted you the code

Comment: you need a complete code to be able to reporduce it

Answer (score 0):

To change the style(image) of sorting icon, you need to change the auto-generated classes of data-table, which you can figure out , when you will 'inspect element'.

Auto-generated classes includes :

```
sorting
sorting_asc
sorting_desc
```

Example according to your code :

```
.table thead th.sorting {
    background-image: url(sort.png); //path of the image you want
}

.table thead th.sorting_asc {
    background-image: url(sort_asc.png); //path of the image you want

}
```